# Topshelf hosting application debugging in VS2010

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I'm trying to use the Topshelf hosting application Topshelf.Host.exe to execute my .NET Class Library as a Windows service. http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/shelving/

I'm having trouble hooking up the debugger inside VS2010. 
Here's what I have setup

- Topshelf.Host.exe at say c:\projects
- my classlibrary service building to c:\projects\Services\library-name\
- running Topshelf.Host.exe as the class library's external application to debug with

With F5/run Topshelf.Host.exe is running, but it doesn't seem to pick up and load my class libary. Any ideas or better ways to set debugging up?

Comment: When you run it standalone, does your code get loaded?  Can you write something to the log file, etc.?

Comment: I tried running the samples in the download and they don't seem to work either, up-voted..

Comment: @Adam Fyles, it seems to be a 4.0 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your library-name.config in that folder to make sure the boostrapper is properly loaded? It should look like http://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/master/src/Samples/StuffOnAShelf/clock.config

Edit: the Topshelf.Host is no longer supported or maintained.

Comment: Thanks Travis. Believe it or not, I'm just getting back to this. I looked into my problem deeper today and I think it involves .NET 4, when I build for 3.5 it works. I'll dig deeper, but any hints would be helpful. T

Comment: Building the TopShelf sources for 4.0 addresses the issue. FYI: 1 warning about obsolete call.