# Windows EXE can run as service or application. How can I determine if it is running as a service or not?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-services

I am looking for a Win32 API call to return the runtime context of my process. I want to be able to programmatically test if I am running as a service or am I running as standard application process.

Several ideas come to mind.... Since I always have service DAD.exe who runs SON.exe sometimes as his child and in service context --- and sometimes SON.exe is started not by DAD, and by a user.

SON.EXE would do API whoami() to learn which context he is running in.

Now DAD could create an environment var -- and then SON could test for this var -- and if found he knows he is a son of DAD and thus runnning as a service..... But this is weak...

Another idea would be to look at my SID or token and see if I could make this determination.... Again this looks at best more complex vs. a single API check...

Comment: Actually I have DAD.EXE, SON.EXE and GSON.EXE where GSON.EXE runs within service context sometimes and sometimes within user context. The point here is that GSON.EXE can not simply ask if his parent is DAD.EXE -- asking if it is SON.EXE is also problematic since in actuality SON.EXE is the common CMD.EXE -- so keying on parent name isn't going to be the right idea...

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You're not trying to determine who the parent is, you are are trying to determine if the parent happens to be a service? Is that right?

Comment: You could do this with OpenProcessToken() + CreateWellKnownSid(WinServiceSid) + CheckTokenMembership()

Comment: Luke could you explain a bet more, I see and can research the API you list -- but how would they yield True when my program is running as a service and fals when running via a user starting it from the users session?

Comment: Zdan, I do not care about who the parent is.... I was just saying that in my case that would not be solid. I am simply want to aske the question if ( running_as_service() ) ras = TRUE else ras = FALSE

Comment: When a process is run as a service, Windows adds SECURITY_SERVICE_RID to its token.

Answer (score 1):

The simple low-tech solution to this is to register your service to run with command line arguments that identify it as a service.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a sizeable install base that don't have this connvention in place.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [Tool Help library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686837%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Using it, you take a snapshot of all the currently running processes and then you can walk through all the processes using the [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Process32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function. These return a structure ([PROCESSENTRY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) that looks like:

```
typedef struct tagPROCESSENTRY32 {
  DWORD     dwSize;
  DWORD     cntUsage;
  DWORD     th32ProcessID;
  ULONG_PTR th32DefaultHeapID;
  DWORD     th32ModuleID;
  DWORD     cntThreads;
  DWORD     th32ParentProcessID;
  LONG      pcPriClassBase;
  DWORD     dwFlags;
  TCHAR     szExeFile[MAX_PATH];
} PROCESSENTRY32, *PPROCESSENTRY32;
```

as you walk through all the processes, as soon as you find the one whose `th32ProcessID` matches the one for SON.exe (see [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ). If the th32ParentProcessID of that structure matches that of DAD.exe, then you know you were launched from DAD.exe.

**Edit:**
Answering your comment, I guess you could go one step further and then see who the parent of DAD.exe is, if it's services.exe, then you're a service.

Comment: cool . . . can this approach give True or False to my base question -- if( running_as_service() ) ras = TRUE else ras = FALSE .... my goal is just to know if program is running in service context or user context . . . .

Comment: cool.... are these api and their process "walking" feature callable when my program is running as an application from within a user session? (without admin elevation etc, e.g. standard user?).... thanks!!!

Comment: @kevinwaite: that's a good question. They should work as a standard user, but you may need to be elevated to see all processes on the system. But that should be enough to tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation, I think you could determine whether you're in an interactive session or service via:

- [`GetProcessWindowStation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683225%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [`GetUserObjectInformation(UOI_FLAGS)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683238%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

and then `WSF_VISIBLE` should tell you.

If you wanted to differentiate between a logged-in user session and one that's inactive (Fast User Switching), I guess you could use [`GetThreadDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and `GetUserObjectInformation(UOI_IO)`.

---

The best and simplest way to tell from inside the service is to set a flag when `ServiceMain` is called.  But you're testing a child process, so see above.

Comment: This will not work when service has registered with `SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS` flag ("Allow service to interact with desktop" in UI). This is unusual and not recommended, but possible.

Comment: @PeterTaran: That depends on what you mean by "works".  The functions will succeed and give accurate information about the "process context" which OP asked about.  That "process context" information may not be 100% correlated with whether it was spawned from a service, but a child process running on the user's desktop, because a service spawned it, is still an application running on the user's desktop.

Comment: Original question was "Is the application launched as a service or not?", so "works" mean "gives an anwer to that question". When service process have configured with `SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS` flag, `GetUserObjectInformation(UOI_IO)` **will** return `WSF_VISIBLE` just like it happens for a process not being service. I speak not about a process, launched by service and interacting with desktop, but about service process itself.

Comment: @PeterTaran: The question doesn't ask about the service process, but a separate application which may have been spawned from a service.  And abuses the phrase "running as a service",  And then the comments make it clear it is actually asking about a grandchild of the service process.

Answer (score 1):

I [found](http://www.google.com/codesearch#y8C6rjU7p5I/trunk/src/base/win_util.cc&type=cs) the following:

```
bool WinUtil::IsServiceUser(HANDLE hToken, bool *is_service) {
  if (is_service == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  TOKEN_STATISTICS ts;
  DWORD dwSize = 0;
  // Use token logon LUID instead of user SID, for brevity and safety
  if (!::GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenStatistics,
                             (LPVOID)&ts, sizeof(ts), &dwSize)) {
    return false;
  }

  // Compare LUID
  const LUID SystemLuid = SYSTEM_LUID;
  const LUID LocalServiceLuid = LOCALSERVICE_LUID;
  const LUID NetworkServiceLuid = NETWORKSERVICE_LUID;
  if (EqualLuid(SystemLuid, ts.AuthenticationId) ||
      EqualLuid(LocalServiceLuid, ts.AuthenticationId) ||
      EqualLuid(NetworkServiceLuid, ts.AuthenticationId)) {
    *is_service = true;
    return true;
  }

  // Not a service account
  *is_service = false;
  return true;
}
bool WinUtil::IsServiceProcess(bool *is_service) {
  if (is_service == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  if (Util::IsVistaOrLater()) {
    // Session 0 is dedicated to services
    DWORD dwSessionId = 0;
    if (!::ProcessIdToSessionId(::GetCurrentProcessId(), &dwSessionId) ||
        (dwSessionId == 0)) {
      *is_service = true;
      return true;
    }
  }

  // Get process token
  HANDLE hProcessToken = NULL;
  if (!::OpenProcessToken(::GetCurrentProcess(),
                          TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE,
                          &hProcessToken)) {
    return false;
  }

  ScopedHandle process_token(hProcessToken);

  // Process token is one for a service account.
  if (!IsServiceUser(process_token.get(), is_service)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Just because a process runs in session 0 or under one of those accounts does not necessarily make it a service, though it is probably good enough for 99.9% of cases.

Comment: @Luke I agree that it isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: re: the code snippet/example above... IsServiceUser() and IsServiceProcess() have a bug for pre Vista OSs environments.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for Topshelf http://topshelf-project.com/, it does the heavy lifting and makes it easier run as console or install as a service. [Topshelf hosting application debugging in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720985/topshelf-hosting-application-debugging-in-vs2010)